# Customize biblatex windycity style

Tags: biblatex, windycity

I'd like to customize [windycity](https://ctan.org/pkg/windycity), which is a `biblatex` implementation of *Chicago Manual of Style*'s 17th edition. If for some reason, `windycity` is very difficult to customize, I'd settle for customizing the default [biblatex-chicago](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) style.

What I would like to change:

1. The first time anything is cited, if it has a `shorttitle`, the short title should appear in the note after the title in brackets. I'll show examples below.
2. In the bibliography, anything that has a `shorttitle` should also show the short title in brackets in its entry. Again, I'll show examples below.

(If anyone cares, this is basically the style for *Oxford Studies in Ancient Philosophy*. See sections 6 & 7 [on their submissions page](http://ancphil.lsa.umich.edu/oxford-studies-in-ancient-philosophy/submissions/) if you're even more curious.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[style=windycity,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@book{ nails2002-people-of-plato,
        author = {Debra Nails},
        title = {The People of Plato},
        shorttitle = {People},
        publisher = {Hackett Publishing},
        year = 2002,
        address = {Indianapolis, IN},
}

@article{ morrison1942,
    author = {J.S. Morrison},
    title = {Meno of Pharsalus, Polycrates, and Ismenias},
        shorttitle = {Meno},
    journal = {Classical Quarterly},
    year = 1942,
    volume = 36,
    number = 1,
    pages = {57--78},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Blah, blah, blah.\footcite[][15]{nails2002-people-of-plato}

Blah, blah, blah.\footcite[][24]{nails2002-people-of-plato} Yada, yada, yada.\footcite[][59--60]{morrison1942}

Yada, yada, yada.\footcite[][62]{morrison1942}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Examples for citations:

- The first citation of the Nails book should look like this:

  > Debra Nails, *The People of Plato* [*People*] (Indianapolis, IN: Hackett Publishing, 2002), 15.
- The first citation of the Morrison article should look like this:

  > J.S. Morrison, “Meno of Pharsalus, Polycrates, and Ismenias” [“Meno”], *Classical Quarterly* 36, no. 1 (1942): 59–60.

Examples for bibliography:

> - Morrison, J.S. “Meno of Pharsalus, Polycrates, and Ismenias” [“Meno”]. *Classical Quarterly* 36, no. 1 (1942): 57–78.
> - Nails, Debra. *The People of Plato* [*People*]. Indianapolis, IN: Hackett Publishing, 2002.

I've read several other questions about customizing `biblatex`, and my guess is that I need to create a personal `biblatex.cfg`, but I am not sure what to add there.

Answer (score 2):

Since `windycity` is an extremely modular style it is enough to redefine the bibmacro `longtitle`. Its original definition doesn't contain the `\iffieldundef{short\xtitle title}` block (see [ll. 1167-1173 of `windycity.bbx` in version 2019/07/17](https://github.com/brianchase/windycity/blob/28993b54b23c38529224d0641c28f883395011c6/bbx/windycity.bbx#L1167-L1173)).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=windycity,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{longtitle}{%
  \printtext[\xtitle title]{%
    \printfield[noformat]{\xtitle title}%
    \iffieldundef{\xtitle subtitle}
      {}
      {\subtitlepunct
       \printfield[noformat]{\xtitle subtitle}}}%
  \iffieldundef{short\xtitle title}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[brackets]{%
       \printfield[\xtitle title]{short\xtitle title}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{nails2002-people-of-plato,
  author     = {Debra Nails},
  title      = {The People of Plato},
  shorttitle = {People},
  publisher  = {Hackett Publishing},
  year       = 2002,
  address    = {Indianapolis, IN},
}
@article{morrison1942,
  author     = {J.S. Morrison},
  title      = {Meno of Pharsalus, Polycrates, and Ismenias},
  shorttitle = {Meno},
  journal    = {Classical Quarterly},
  year       = 1942,
  volume     = 36,
  number     = 1,
  pages      = {57--78},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just for the example
Blah, blah, blah.\footcite[][15]{nails2002-people-of-plato}

Blah, blah, blah.\footcite[][24]{nails2002-people-of-plato}
Yada, yada, yada.\footcite[][59--60]{morrison1942}

Yada, yada, yada.\footcite[][62]{morrison1942}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Morrison, J.S. “Meno of Pharsalus, Polycrates, and Ismenias” [“Meno”]. Classical Quarterly 36, no. 1 (1942): 57–78.//Nails, Debra. The People of Plato [People]. Indianapolis, IN: Hackett Publishing, 2002.]

It is enough to simply add this redefinition to your document preamble. If you want to, you can add it to `biblatex.cfg`, but that seems more hassle than it is worth.

Comment: Simple and perfect: thanks very much!

Comment: Note from the future (2023-12-02): this method does not work with [the latest version of windycity](https://github.com/brianchase/windycity). I will try to take a look and figure out what changed, but if you reach here via Google, this isn't working currently.